# Burninate the [unlocking] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

The [unlocking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unlocking) tag seems too generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no questions with [unlocking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unlocking) anymore, the system should delete the tag automatically in some time.

Comment: +1... although I have to ask, are the new tags you introduced really useful? `pdf-unlocking`? `core-unlock`? They are much more specific, but isn't it too narrow a niche?

Comment: @DanielBeck I _am_ inclined to think it's too narrow a niche, but will monitor the progress for a week and remove them, if there aren't any new questions on those tags

Comment: Sounds good. Give it a month though, and perhaps require more than one question.

Comment: @DanielBeck Thanks, Will do.